# Echo input in PHP

Tags: php, html, input, echo, isset

Can someone help me with this. Im trying to echo an input with isset as value in php but i'm getting difficulties with the commas.

```
echo '<td><input class="text" type="text" id="txtLogin" name="txtLogin" value="<?= isset($_POST['"txtLogin"']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['"txtLogin"']) : '' ></td>';
```

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need opening tag for PHP script again. `<?=` before `isset()` is wrong. The `=` sign means `echo` and now you have: `echo "some string<?php echo 'another string'" ` etc... which is wrong. Use dots for separating strings and PHP code, e.g. `echo 'String '. some_php_stuff() . 'another string';`

Answer (score 4):

A cleaner solution will be :

```
$txtLogin = isset($_POST['"txtLogin"']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['"txtLogin"']) : "";
echo '<td><input class="text" type="text" id="txtLogin" name="txtLogin" value="'. $txtLogin .'"></td>';
```

This is good rather than adding conditional statements inside quotes

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
<?php
echo '<td><input class="text" type="text" id="txtLogin" name="txtLogin" value="' . isset($_POST['txtLogin']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['txtLogin']) : '' . '></td>';
?>
```

Comment: You are missing a single quote after the double quotes in value

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
echo '<td><input class="text" type="text" id="txtLogin" name="txtLogin" value="'.isset($_POST['"txtLogin"']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['"txtLogin"']) : "".'"></td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just concatenate strings an expressions like this:

```
echo '<td><input class="text" type="text" id="txtLogin" name="txtLogin" value="' . (isset($_POST['"txtLogin"']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['"txtLogin"']) : '') . '"></td>';
```

Comment: @Manuel. There should be a closing double quote for value